# What are the typical values for squeezed states of light?

Tags: quantum-optics

Which range of values of the squeezing parameter is achievable with today's technology ?

Comment: According to a document by Alain Aspect edition of 2006: "Different experiences have produced for
compressed states corresponding to compression factors of up to 10."

Comment: The title of the document after translation is: Quantum optics 2: photon, tome 1 ,Alain Aspect, Philippe Grangier.

Comment: That seems to have been [bettered in 2016](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.110801).